# How to retrieve data from database child reference inside another child reference, both generated by push()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
Orders
     .
     .
     . -KpZUeqhsuv8cb8zxUQk
     .       . -KpZUeqhsuv8cb8zxUQl
     .       .      desc: "1/4 Fried Chicken"
     .       .      price: 70
     .       .      qty: 2
     .       . -KpZUeqhsuv8cb8zxUQm
     .       .      desc: "Apple and Citrus Blend"
     .       .      price: 120
     .       .      qty: 1
     .       . -KpZUeqhsuv8cb8zxUQn
     .              desc: "1/4 Fried Chicken"
     .              price: 250
     .              qty: 0
     . -KpZUeqi8Cy2VI3qpEnp
     . -KpZXtq2o6mLnMKb_w3m
     . -KpZb7aBuahEQXh4EWaR
```

I have this set of data in my firebase real-time database and I need to retrieve it and display inside a recyclerview but an at loss as how to go about it. I have the basics of retrieving data but this seems complex and advanced. Any kind of assistance is highly appreciated.https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERd5N.png

Comment: Try getting object keys using `Object.keys(orders)` and then iterate keys using loop?

Comment: -KpZUeqhsuv8cb8zxUQk why are you generating like this, it will querying much more completed.

Comment: tell me what is your need so that i can tell you a solution which will be helpful for you. I don't understand why you're nesting your data like that in the firebase tree

Comment: @ MuruGan, I am making an e-commerce app. I want when a customer places an order, the order is added to the database reference "Orders" and the individual items are added uniquely for purposes of retrieving them into a recycleview. I don't know if I am clear enough...